# One crayon-rail-games tag to rule them all?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have two questions tagged [empire-builder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empire-builder) and [one about the Eurorails family of games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/erasable-yet-bold-crayon-for-empire-builder-games-e-g-eurorails) that doesn't have a game tag at all.  We could of course create a "eurorails" tag, but that question applies as well to Empire Builder, Iron Dragon, Lunar Rails, and all the others.  Really, all the "crayon rail games" are of a class, with the differences among them being akin to the differences among versions or expansions of other games.

Does it make sense to tag questions about these games with some over-arching tag and not with the individual tags?  If I'm looking for questions about Empire Builder, I'd probably want to see the Nippon Rails questions too, at least until the bucket gets huge.

Should we have one tag, and if so what should it be called?  Eurorails-family?  Crayon-rails?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [crayon-rail-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crayon-rail-games). See e.g. the [list at BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/crayon_rail_games#).

Comment: I think if it has support on BGG, it makes sense to use a similar tag.

Comment: I'm inclined to go with this -- tag the Eurorails question with this tag and then make empire-builder a synonym.  Any objections?